# Definition of Concavity for Twice Differentiable Functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x)$ be a twice-differentiable function. The definitions for concave upward and concave downward I found in my textbooks are all somewhat wordy, something along the lines of:

> Definition 1: $f(x)$ is **concave upward** at $c$ if $f(x) > [f(c)+f(c)(x−c)]$ for all $x$ in some open interval containing $c$.

(See [here](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/secondderiv/) for example.)

Why don't we simply use the following definition:

> Proposed Definition 2: $f(x)$ is **concave upward** at $c$ if $f''(c) > 0 $

Are there cases where $f''(c) > 0$, but Definition 1 is not satisfied? Aren't Definitions 1 and 2 equivalent?

Comment: Definition 1 is more general because not all functions are twice-differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to prove yourself the equivalence between the two assertions in the case of the function $f$ is two time differentiable, it is quite easy.

$f$ two time diffenrentiable, 
$f(x) > [f(c)+(x-c)f(c)] \Rightarrow f'(x) > f(x) \Rightarrow f''(x) > 0$ 
and the other way...

But consider that a function can be not two time differentiable yet still convexe. The first definition is more general.